# Excel formatting to correct dp

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, cells

I'm looking to format excel cells such that whatever number I put in is the value it displays. i.e. at the moment when typing in 0.69374767047, the value it reads as is 0.69374767. But I also have numbers like; 0.00305 which come out correctly. Is there a way to format the cell so whatever number I put will come out to the correct decimal place and also that there is no 0s on the end of the number, as I need to do things later with that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you would have to modify the cell number format in a Worksheet_Change for each entry; setting the number of decimal place (up to the maximum of 15 significant digits).

Comment: Theres several thousands data points so thats why I came here, forgot to mention

Comment: So maybe you require a module sub instead of an event macro. Same solution applies.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that>

Comment: I mean that you should start by tapping [alt]+[F11] then typing some code. When you run into trouble, come back to edit your question and include your own effort together with a description of any problems and/or error messages. People coming here asking for code are **expected** to show their own effort.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can do it without code, just custom cell format and put 0.,### so it will give at least an integer and any dp if needed. 
e.g. 
   Input         Output
   12            12
   4.305         4.305
   3.2           3.2

Comment: Good catch! I played with this a bit and couldn't get it working until I tried `0.0##############` as a format mask. Of course, the columns need to be wide enough to see all of the digits or `########` will be displayed.